# How to run only one junit test case in maven?

Tags: maven, junit

I'm working on [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) project, it uses `mvn`. It has plenty of test cases, I want to run only one of the test cases from a test class. Googling around I found the solution to be:

```
mvn -Dtest=TestClass#method test
```

but running this on guava project says:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
There are no tests to run.

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

(note that I passed real testclass and corresponding method, while running the above command)

Where I'm making the mistake? I'm new to maven build tool, couldn't able to figure out where I'm making mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, that Guava is currently using an [old version](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/04ed59121f88861eb24d59de0a0c66aa5400c748/pom.xml#L182) (2.7.2) of the maven-surefire-plugin which does not yet support the `-Dtest=TestClass#method` syntax. This feature was introduced starting with version [2.7.3](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#test):

> Since 2.7.3, you can execute a limited number of methods in the test by adding #myMethod or #my*ethod. For example, "-Dtest=MyTest#myMethod". This is supported for junit 4.x and testNg.

Comment: Then I guess I can fork the repo and upgrade to the version which supports the format we are discussing..

Comment: @Ant's Exactly. You could also submit a Pull Request back to the Guava project with your update.

Comment: It works! Thanks. But last question, in this format we can't run say 5 or 6 test cases?

Comment: @Ant's According to the documentation you should be able to add several patterns separated by commas. Also regular expressions are supported. See http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#test